# Flutter Dio : DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [429]

Tags: flutter, dio

Can anyone help me out how to solve this error. I am trying to build an RESTAPI with Flutter DIO. I am trying to Update my user profile. But when I open my keyboard in mobile using TextField or TextFormField , I am getting this error. I dont have any idea why its showing this error and once I open my keyboard in mobile ,DIO is getting all GET request automatically.

```
I/flutter ( 5005): Error : DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [429]
```

Dependency:

```
  dio: ^3.0.10
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 429 means, you sent too many requests.
so make sure that you set (connectTimeout & receiveTimeout) at Dio(BaseOptions()) .. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple
According to the attached image, you sent too many requests
Therefore, you can log in to the https://newsapi.org page with another account and get a new API and Put it in place of the old one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSfdw.png)

Comment: English only please.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).